# Google Developer Console hidden useful java.lang crash errors headers unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mobile, crash-reports, google-developers-console

In the past, google used to show java.lang.errors from unity games like this:

```
java.lang.Error: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Version '2019.4.35f1 (0462406dff2e)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'arm64-v8a'
Build fingerprint: 'HUAWEI/ANE-LX1/HWANE:9/HUAWEIANE-L21/9.1.0.368C432:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2022-04-12 15:03:27+0200
pid: 15181, tid: 15265, name: UnityMain  >>> com.lockwoodpublishing.avakinlife <<<
uid: 10870
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x10
Cause: null pointer dereference
x0  00000072303fd658  x1  00000072cf315f18  x2  0000000000000000  x3  0000000000000006
x4  00000000000002b2  x5  0000000000000000  x6  00000000ffffff50  x7  0000000000000001
x8  00000072cf315ed8  x9  0000000000000000  x10 00000072cf315ed8  x11 0000000000000000
x12 0000000000000000  x13 00000072303fd458  x14 00000000ffffff50  x15 0000000000000040
x16 00000072ceed66f0  x17 0000007376b46e08  x18 0000007240001020  x19 00000072303fd600
x20 0000000000000000  x21 00000072303fd658  x22 0000000000000000  x23 00000072302aead0
x24 0000000000000001  x25 00000072cf316078  x26 0000007230065f70  x27 00000072ceea96a8
x28 0000000000000000  x29 00000072cf316058
sp  00000072cf315ed0  lr  00000072ce078244  pc  00000072ce08f1a8
```

This was really helpful in combination with the smart symbolicate tool (https://github.com/brunomikoski/UnitySmartSymbolicate) to deobfuscate unity crashes.
But looks like google is now hiding this information and only showing like this:

```
java.lang.Error: 
  at 
  at 
  at 
  at 
  at 
  at 
  at 
  at 
  at 
  at 
  at 
  at 
  at 
  at 
  at 
  at 
  at libunity.0x95ffba (Native Method)
  at libunity.0x2a96a5 (Native Method)
  at libunity.0x2a5d0f (Native Method)
  at libunity.0x2a5c25 (Native Method)
```

And since is missing the ABI from the crash it's impossible to know for sure how to symbolicate this.

*Keep in mind the two errors displayed here are different, that's why the stack trace looks completely different.*

This is some new settings somewhere?? Its like this to everyone?

Comment: Could be a change in the assembly stripping settings perhaps?

Comment: Hum I really don't think so @turnipinrut, because even older issues now are displayed without it.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this error? If yes then please let me know the steps, I'm currently working in unity error reporting at a native level and I might be able to help, and I'm also very curious about it. Even if you don't know the exact steps, even just knowing what version of unity, the build settings and the android version might be enough to go with. Also do you have the error class?

Comment: @turnipinrut hum if you are talking about the exact error on the examples I posted, nop I could not find a good reproduction step, but I'm still seeing it 
happening from time to time. 
I see that java.lang errors for quite a while, even before unity 2017. I would love to hear more about this tool that you are working on, it could be incredibly helpful!

Comment: it's this https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-unity